# How do you access the query string in Flask routes?

Tags: python, flask, query-string

How do you access query parameters or the query string in Flask routes? It's not obvious from the Flask documentation.

The example route `/data` below illustrates the context that I would like to access that data. If someone requests something like `example.com/data?abc=123`, I would like access to the string `?abc=123` or to be able to retrieve the value of parameters like `abc`.

```
@app.route("/data")
def data():
    # query_string = ???
    return render_template("data.html")
```

Comment: If you want to receive this string you should use a sqlite or a mysql query.
create a variable call "query_string" and use flask to mitage it with other functions and variables. While using Flask you can edit your "query_strings" highly and put them with other self made tags and imports. 
I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1163, accepted):

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/data')
def data():
    # here we want to get the value of user (i.e. ?user=some-value)
    user = request.args.get('user')
```

Comment: This example returns that value of the "user" parameter passed in the query string, not the query string itself.

"Query string" means everything after the question mark and before the pound sign, if one is present.

Comment: still is a useful answer consider that it is related to the question. So valid and +1

Comment: Will this raise an exception if user is not present? (I guess not if args is just a dict.)

Comment: No - as with a dict and .get, you'd just get None.

Comment: @LyndsySimon: Well spotted. But since this answer correctly answers the question my Google search terms alluded to ('flask get request parameter') I'm up-voting it anyhow. I'm a pedant too, but I'm chalking this up to web mysticism. 

Comment: No argument from me! My comments on this question have been an ongoing source of SO points and overall karma. :) Happy hacking!

Comment: @Necronet it's not useful if, like OP, you need the actual string.

Comment: I am using your suggestion, but I can not input a value with space like `software solutions`. How to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: This may happen when the query string is not url encoded. Please look at the server log for two cases

Encoded URL will be "GET /data?user=krace%20kumar HTTP/1.1" 200"
Unencoded URL will be  "GET /data?user=krace kumar HTTP/1.1" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -

Answer (score 327):

The full URL is available as `request.url`, and the query string is available as `request.query_string.decode()`.

Here's an example:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/adhoc_test/')
def adhoc_test():

    return request.query_string
```

To access an individual known param passed in the query string, you can use `request.args.get('param')`. This is the "right" way to do it, as far as I know.

ETA: Before you go further, you should ask yourself why you want the query string. I've never had to pull in the raw string - Flask has mechanisms for accessing it in an abstracted way. You should use those unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: Im not sure why the answer says `ETA: Before you go further, you should ask yourself why you want the query string`, because if your API has OAuth kind of authentication mechanism, I think you will need to read query params, (not quite sure if I'm correct this about Flask since I started learning Flask today!)

Comment: @HasinthaAbeykoon yes, but in that case, you should not need to ingest the entire querystring, you should know which keys you need to check, and request those keys specifically via `request.args.get`.

Comment: For reference, a "compelling reason not to" can for example be server-side image maps, as those aren't key=value pairs.

Comment: Or if something like proxying a request to another route or app, you might just want to append the raw querystring to the new url.

Answer (score 25):

I came here looking for the query string, not how to get values from the query string.

`request.query_string` returns the URL parameters as raw byte string (Ref 1).

Example of using `request.query_string`:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_query_string():
    return request.query_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Output:

[image: query parameters in Flask route]

**References:**

1. [Official API documentation on query_string](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.query_string)

Answer (score 22):

We can do this by using request.query_string.

Example:

Lets consider view.py

```
from my_script import get_url_params

@app.route('/web_url/', methods=('get', 'post'))
def get_url_params_index():
    return Response(get_url_params())
```

You also make it more modular by using Flask Blueprints - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/

Lets consider first name is being passed as a part of query string
/web_url/?first_name=john

```
## here is my_script.py

## import required flask packages
from flask import request
def get_url_params():
    ## you might further need to format the URL params through escape.    
    firstName = request.args.get('first_name') 
    return firstName
```

As you see this is just a small example - you can fetch multiple values + formate those and use it or pass it onto the template file.

Answer (score 17):

Werkzeug/Flask as already parsed everything for you. No need to do the same work again with urlparse:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/data')
def data():
    query_string = request.query_string  ## There is it
    return render_template("data.html")
```

The full documentation for the request and response objects is in Werkzeug: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/

Answer (score 12):

**Try like this for query string:**

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/parameters', methods=['GET'])
def query_strings():

    args1 = request.args['args1']
    args2 = request.args['args2']
    args3 = request.args['args3']

    return '''<h1>The Query String are...{}:{}:{}</h1>''' .format(args1,args2,args3)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: After many years it solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Thankful watching my solution @Djangodev

Answer (score 7):

*Every form of the query string retrievable from flask request object as described in [O'Reilly Flask Web Devleopment](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920031116.do):*

From [O'Reilly Flask Web Development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920031116.do), and as stated by Manan Gouhari earlier, first you need to import request:

```
from flask import request
```

`request` is an object exposed by Flask as a context variable named (you guessed it) `request`. As its name suggests, it contains *all* the information that the client included in the HTTP request. This object has many attributes and methods that you can retrieve and call, respectively.

You have quite a few `request` attributes which contain the query string from which to choose. Here I will list every attribute that contains in any way the query string, as well as a description from the O'Reilly book of that attribute.

First there is `args` which is "a dictionary with all the arguments passed in the query string of the URL." So if you want the query string parsed into a dictionary, you'd do something like this:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/'):
    queryStringDict = request.args
```

*(As others have pointed out, you can also use `.get('<arg_name>')` to get a specific value from the dictionary)*

Then, there is the `form` attribute, which does *not* contain the query string, but which is included in part of another attribute that *does* include the query string which I will list momentarily. First, though, `form` is "A dictionary with all the form fields submitted with the request." I say that to say this: there is another dictionary attribute available in the flask request object called `values`. `values` is "A dictionary that combines the values in `form` and `args`." Retrieving that would look something like this:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/'):
    formFieldsAndQueryStringDict = request.values
```

*(Again, use `.get('<arg_name>')` to get a specific item out of the dictionary)*

Another option is `query_string` which is "The query string portion of the URL, as a raw binary value." Example of that:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/'):
    queryStringRaw = request.query_string
```

Then as an added bonus there is `full_path` which is "The path and query string portions of the URL." Por ejemplo:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/'):
    pathWithQueryString = request.full_path
```

And finally, `url`, "The complete URL requested by the client" (which includes the query string):

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/'):
    pathWithQueryString = request.url
```

Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 6):

I prefer

```py
user = request.args['user'] if 'user' in request.args else 'guest'
```

over

```py
user = request.args.get('user')
```

this way, you can check the url actually contains the query string first

Comment: Why not user = request.args.get('user', 'guest') ?

Comment: Yep yours is better!
I'm not sure, I think my team is using an older version of flask when I tried it didn't work as expected..

Answer (score 3):

The implementation below worked for me.

```
from flask import request
def getVerificationStatus():
try:
    requestId=int(request.args.get('requestId'))
    print(requestId)
    status= verificationStepRepository.getVerificationStatus(requestId)
    return tb.responsify(200, "success", status)
except Exception as e:
    return errorHandler.dispatchInternalServerError(str(e))
```

Answer (score 3):

Often we just want to map the whole query string into an appropriate python data structure and take it from there. The appropriate structure is a multi-dictionary because keywords can repeat, for example we need to handle `A=123&A=456&B=789`. A multi-dictionary is a list of 2-tuples where each 2-tuple contains the key as its first item and the list of values as its second, so the above goes to `[('A',['123','456']),('B',['789'])]`. All of this is achieved by

```
qstr = request.args.lists() # A generator for the multi-dict
qstr = list(qstr) # To get the actual multi-dict
```

If all you want is a dictionary where the first occurrence of a duplicate keyword is used you can just go

```
qstr = request.args.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the request if GET and we passed some query parameters then,

```
fro`enter code here`m flask import request
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/data')
def data():
   if request.method == 'GET':
      # Get the parameters by key
      arg1 = request.args.get('arg1')
      arg2 = request.args.get('arg2')
      # Generate the query string
      query_string="?arg1={0}&arg2={1}".format(arg1, arg2)
      return render_template("data.html", query_string=query_string)
```

Comment: You may wish to fix the glaring typo in your first line.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `request.args.get()`.
For example if your query string has a field `date`, it can be accessed using

```
date = request.args.get('date')
```

Don't forget to add "`request`" to list of imports from flask,
i.e.

```
from flask import request
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code worked for me:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def search():
   query = request.args
   for key,value in query.items():
      print(key,value)
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```