# Accessing passed value from hyperlink in html (+jinja2)

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to pass a value `row[0]` to a html hyperlink below.
It looks like I can use `{{}}` to do this in jinja2 and
I did confirm that the url changed accordingly.

```
<a href="/editcontact?sid={{row[0]}}">EDIT</a>
```

The problem is I don't know how to retrieve this passed data in the linked html page below.
★★★ is where I want to put the passed `row[0]` value.

```
<form action='/editcontact' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='sid' value='★★★' placeholder='id'>
    ...
    <input type=submit value='MODIFY'>
</form>
```

This is html with jinja2 template, and the server language is python(+flask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have passed in your `sid` as a query parameter in `<a href="/editcontact?sid={{row[0]}}">EDIT</a>`, you can use the following flask code to read the query parameter in the destination page.

```
user = request.args.get('sid')
```

You can then use normal jinja2 interpolation like `{{user}}`

For more details on how to get query parameters in flask, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774265/how-do-you-get-a-query-string-on-flask)