# How to handle unexpected url parameter in Flask

Tags: python, web, url, flask, backend

I'm new to Flask and web development. I have a question about url parameters.

For example, I have an endpoint '/categories' which expect no url arguments. I experimented adding some random url parameter in curl like

```
curl localhost:5000/categories?page=1
```

It works like normal, I'm wondering if that is the expected behavior or should I handle this with some error or warning?

Also, if I expect an url parameter called 'id' and the request contains no url parameter or wrong url parameter. How should I handle this situation?

What status code should I abort in the above situations?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/24892035/12002411

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inspect your query string (the values after ? in the URL) to see if the parameter exists and the value is valid. There are libraries to do this with a decorator, but you can do it manually as well. You will need to import the request object at the top of your module.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/categories')
def categories():
    id = request.args.get('id') # will return None if key does not exist
    if id:
        # id exists, validate value here
        pass
    else:
        # no id, return error or something
        pass
```

Related question:
[How do you get a query string on Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774265/how-do-you-get-a-query-string-on-flask)

Comment: I would like to add that you can pass more args to the request.args.get as a default value and a type [Werkzeug Doc](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict): like  get(key, default=None, type=None),