# How to get query parameters from POST request using python

Tags: python, rest, get

I have the below `py` code:

```
@app.route('/v1/api/checkCurrentWeather?city=Tel-aviv')
def check_current_weather_by_city():
    city = None
```

How Do I get the city parameter from the `GET` request?

I'm working with this [service](https://openweathermap.org/current).

Comment: Why did you put `city` in `@app.route`? I think your question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774265/how-do-you-access-the-query-string-in-flask-routes

Comment: Have you tried putting methods = ['GET' , 'POST'] in your header?