# Trying to pass two parameters from an html form in flask (in url) to then run in a python program

Tags: python, html, flask, get

I'm pretty new to this and I have a python algorithm which I want to run with two parameters that I get from an html form. Here is my html code:

```
<form action="result/">
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" method = "post" type="text" placeholder="Playlist URI" required name="URI"></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" method = "post" type="text" placeholder="Spotify Username" required name="Username"></p>
      <p>
        <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit
        </button>
      </p>
    </form>
```

It redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:5000/result/?URI=b&Username=c, when I input b and c into the form.

I can't figure out how to accept them as parameters though, and it just returns this error:

> 404 Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

My python code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/result.html/<URI>&<username>')
def result(URI,username):
    return render_template("result.html", uri=URI, username=username)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you access the query string in Flask routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774265/how-do-you-access-the-query-string-in-flask-routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access parameters in get request using request in flask

example:

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/result.html")
def result():
    uri = request.args.get("uri")
    username = request.args.get("username")
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I can display the inputs on my result page. I want to use the variables uri and username I pull from the html form to run in my python algorithm and then display the results on the result page. Where would I paste my algorithm and use the uri and username within it? This is my flask code, can I just paste the code for my algorithm under def result? Or should it be in the result.html or elsewhere?: @app.route('/result/')
def result():
 uri = request.args.get("URI")
 username = request.args.get("Username")
 return render_template("result.html", URI = uri, USER=username)

Comment: Can I use {% my algorithm code in python... %} or something like that

Comment: no it is always recommended to do processing in your code not in template