# How to use selenium in Flask

Tags: python, api, selenium, flask

How can i use selenium in my flask api i am trying to make an api which takes url as input and returns  the title of that page but its not working

```
from selenium import webdriver
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/try1/<string:url>")
def yt_downloader(url):
    path = r"D:\\Chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.get(url) 
    return(driver.title)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[This is the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUB50.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to pass an URL as parameter, you rather want to use a query parameter (e.g. try1?url=ADDRESS) or send the URL via a POST Request.

Using a Website URL and its' path within a path parameter is a pretty bad idea.

You can use a query parameter like this in a request:

```
from flask import request
url = request.args.get('url')
```

Comment: thanks for help but can you tell me where to write this line because i am not sure and code is throwing big errors also do i have to make any other changes in code? Thanks for help

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the late reply, check the Flask documentation for further explanation, they offer great examples: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#accessing-request-data There's also a SO Post about getting the query parameter data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774265/how-do-you-access-the-query-string-in-flask-routes - Here I created a snippet, which I tested, it's working fine for me: https://pastebin.com/DjDpxPAX